# Is possible to create a Windows Service in Windows Runtime?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime

I have a library compiled for Windows Runtime Component only. I need to call this library from my Windows Service. Is it possible? Is possible to write a backend in Windows Runtime?

Comment: I think it should be possible as long as you're not using any WinRT APIs that are store apps only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible. Only system trigerred background task are supported.